# Get price of an order, by manufacturer or brand on MAGENTO

Tags: php, magento

I am developing a module to receive commissions from companies that are selling in my Magento store. It is already working, but need to add a new feature that I'm not getting.
I need to add an extra value in the commission, if the application of any company is greater than "X"
I did in a way that did not work:

```
foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $key => $item)
{
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
    $price = $item->getPrice();
    $valor_comissao = (int)$product->getAttributeText('comissao_vendedor')/100;
    $comissao_valor2= $price-($price*$valor_comissao);
    $qty = $item->getQtyOrdered();
    $valor_pedido= ($price*$qty);
    if($valor_pedido > 150) {
        $comissao_valor= ($comissao_valor2*$qty-17);
    } else {
        $comissao_valor=($comissao_valor2*$qty-2);
    }
           $comissoes[] = array (
                                                    'Razao' => 'Produto '.$item->getName().' id '.$item->getProductId().' x '.$item->getQtyToInvoice().' sku: '. $item->getSku(),
                                                    'Login' => $product->getAttributeText('login'),
                                                    'ValorFixo' => $comissao_valor
                                                );
    }
```

then only if the product go from $ 150.00 the value is added and if you have two selections from costing $ 100.00, the value is not added. I need the value to be added if the entire order of the brand exceeds $ 150.00.

The logic that I'm trying to follow is as follows:

- Taking the total value of the order
- Filter by tags, ie total value of the order by brand
- If the product is a brand that exceeded "x" and she has not yet received the additional value, add shipping

I wonder if someone has gone through something similar and could help me.

Grateful.

Answer (score 0):

> Taking the total value of the order

You can retrieve the total of the order via:

```
$order->getGrandTotal()
```

> Filter by tags, ie total value of the order by brand

I would recommend using Magento's resource model object and building a query on it.

This post shows how this can be done: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5139391/3784145

**note**

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
```

can be used instead of

```
Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
```

Explanation on the difference between Model and Resource:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/4579

> If the product is a brand that exceeded "x" and she has not yet received the additional value, add shipping

I don't really know what you mean with: **If the product is a brand that exceeded "x"**

But I think this would require another collection query.